# Converting SQL query into regex

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

can you provide me with confirmation whether I correctly converted following SQL Queries into regex expression?

1) 
SQL:

```
CLASSIFICATION_CODE not like '24%'
```

REGEX:

```
CLASSIFICATION_CODE <> '([^2]|2[^4])'
```

2) 
SQL:

```
TYPE_CODE NOT LIKE 'DKRI%' OR TYPE_CODE  NOT LIKE 'KRI%' OR TYPE_CODE  <> '355' OR TYPE_CODE  <> '303'
```

REGEX:

```
TYPE_CODE <> '([^DK3]|D[^K]|DK[^R]|DKR[^I]|K[^R]|KR[^I]|3[^50]|30[^3]|35[^5]'
```

Thanks in advance,

a.

Comment: Which language are you using to convert? Also, your regex patterns are incorrect: `NOT LIKE 'DKRI%'` would convert to `^DKRI` and `<> 355` would convert to `^355`

Comment: I am using Oracle's DB regex.

Comment: You're using Oracle DB regex to convert?

Comment: Well, to be precise - I do use SQL Extensions toolkit for Netezza which is pretty much the same as Oracle one.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Regular expressions match anywhere, but `like` is always the full string.  So you need to anchor the regular expressions:

```
regexp_like(CLASSIFICATION_CODE, '^([^2]|2[^4])'
```

Although, I would write this as:

```
not regexp_like(CLASSIFICATION_CODE, '^24')
```

Your second is much simpler:

```
CLASSIFICATION_CODE IS NOT NULL
```

or:

```
regexp_like(CLASSIFICATION_CODE, '.')
```

I could speculate that you really intend `AND` between the conditions, but with `OR`, any string is going to match.